# A basic problem on convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Can we have two distribution functions whose set of continuities are disjoint set and still $F_n$ converge to both in distribution

Answer (score 1):

The set of discontinuities of a distribution function is denumerable.  The union of two sets of discontinuities of two d.f.s is also denumerable.  Hence, the intersection of their continuity points is an subset of the line of countable complement.  Your situation cannot inhere.